# What does POI stand for in the context of 7 Days to Die?

Tags: terminology, 7-days-to-die

So, Alpha 9.1 for 7 Days to Die just hit STEAM.

I'm going through [**the release notes**](http://7daystodie.com/alpha-9-1-get-it-while-its-hot/) within the changes and fixes they mention `POI`, such as:

> - Lightly increased chance to find Wilderness POIs in random gen
> - Fixed random gen wilderness POI placement
> - Fixed random gen wilderness POI terrain trimming
> - Fixed terrain in random gen around wilderness POIs being cut down to dirt and clay

At first I thought it stands for `Place of interest`, `Point of interest` or `Person of interest` but that doesn't seem to fit the context of the sentences.

Does it stand for one of the before mentioned or does it stand for something completely different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more STEAM-forum crawling it seems it indeed means **Point of Interest**.

In addition POIs are represented by brown-ish rectangles (not 100% sure on the color) on the map which if you find them is not a good location to build a base in as these are areas most likely to be chosen for Zombie spawns.

---

#### References (I could find)

---

- [**http://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/35219681803930408/**](http://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/35219681803930408/)
- [**http://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/46476691929638176/**](http://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/46476691929638176/)
- [**http://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/540743212295289341/**](http://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/540743212295289341/) (Some posts down in the thread)

Answer (score 1):

As you've thought, and even outside of games, POI can refer to **P**lace, **P**oint, or **P**erson **O**f **I**nterest.
**Ref: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_interest)**
In this context and based on the release notes, I would agree with [Fançois](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/181889/120430) in saying that "place of interest" is correct. Considering the second bullet point specifically:

> - Fixed random gen wilderness POI placement

This would mean that the generation of interesting places in the wilderness has been improved in this release.